# Restaurant Shorthand

Tags: code-golf, search

## Goal

Sometimes dinner menus can have long winded names.  It's much easier for the waiter to write an abbreviation that unambiguously identifies the dish.

For example, given this list:

```
beef burger
chicken burger
chicken nuggets
```

The abbreviation `c n` matches `chicken nuggets`.
The abbreviation `bur` matches `beef burger` and `chicken burger`.

Write a program of function that identifies one or more items that match an abbreviation.

## Input

1. The abbreviated string to find.
2. A list of items to search.

You may change this order and use any suitable data types.

## Output

- If the abbreviation does not match any items: `Not found`
- If the abbreviation unambiguously matches an item: output the unabbreviated item.
- If the abbreviation ambiguously matches several items: output a comma separated list of words that would make the selection unambiguous, followed by a question mark.  The order is not important.  Extra spaces are permitted.

## Matching rules

Each word in the abbreviation and the items is considered separately.  If an abbreviated word matches the start of an item word, the item is a potential match.  If none of an item's words start with any if the abbreviated words, that item is not a match.

Abbreviated words can be in any order.

An abbreviated word cannot be used to match multiple item words and visa-versa.

Abbreviations only match the start of words.

Assume no item will contain all of the words of another item.  For example, you will never have `beef burger` and `beef cheese burger`.

## Test Cases

Given this list:

```
beef burger
crispy chicken burger
grilled chicken burger
chicken nuggets
chocolate cone
strawberry cone
vanilla cone
```

These abbreviation give the specified output:

```
fish           Not found
cones          Not found
chicken cone   Not found
nilla          Not found
v              vanilla cone
be             beef burger
c n            chicken nuggets
b b            beef burger
c b c          crispy chicken burger
c b            crispy,grilled?
bu             beef,crispy,grilled?
            or beef,crispy chicken,grilled chicken?
ch             crispy,grilled,nuggets,cone?
            or crispy chicken,grilled chicken,nuggets,cone?
```

## Scoring

This is code golf.  The shortest answer in bytes in 12 days wins acceptance.  (I would have made it one week, but I won't be around for that.)

Comment: I'm not certain why *An abbreviated word cannot be used to match multiple item words* would be important if `v` matches `vanilla cone`.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47131/20469)

Comment: @Dennis, if an abbreviated word matched multiple item words, `c b` would match `crispy chicken burger` instead of being ambiguous.  When I say "word" I mean a string of characters delimited by a space, so `g c b` is three words.

Comment: *If the abbreviation ambiguously matches several items: output a comma separated list of words that would make the selection unambiguous.* Does that refer to a word that, by itself, would allow to choose from the matching options, or in addition to the abbreviations? With the first interpretation, `crispy,grilled,nuggets,chocolate` should be valid for the `ch` test case? With the second interpretation, `chicken,grilled` should be valid for the `c b` test case. What am I missing?

Comment: Given input `b b` `beef burger` `battered bacon` what would be acceptable output?

Comment: @Dennis, I'd expect a word that isn't matched.  While `chocolate` would make it unambiguous, it was matched by `ch` so I'd expect `cone` instead.  As for `c b`, I think your solution of `chicken,grilled` is an ingenious interpretation!  However, what does that mean for `c c`?  Damn it.  I should have sandboxed this.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, good point.  Any one word from either would fulfil the criteria.  I considered "output all items that match", but that seemed too simple.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 - 181 bytes

It turns the abbreviated string into a regex and attempts to match groups from the search list.

The ternary operation `if` and `else`s are 14 bytes. I've tried to cut it down into a list and then accessing one of the items based on the state of `r`, but don't have anything shorter that this yet.

```
import re
def s(a,l):
 r=[m.group(1)for e in l for m in[re.compile('^('+a.replace(' ','\w+ ')+'\w+)$').search(e)]if m]
 print','.join(r)+'?'if len(r)>1 else r[0]if r else'Not found'
```

Call with `s(str, list)`:

```
s('c n', ['chicken burger', 'chicken nuggets', 'cheeseburger'])
>>> chicken nuggets
s('c n', ['chicken burger', 'chicken nuggets', 'cheeseburger', 'chicken nuggets with sauce', 'foobar'])
>>> chicken nuggets
s('c n', ['chicken burger', 'chicken nuggets', 'cheeseburger', 'chicken nuggets with sauce', 'foobar', 'cfoo nbar'])
>>> chicken nuggets,cfoo nbar?
```